# Optimal type for file read/write buffer

Tags: c, alignment

For a long time, I used simple `char[]` buffer when reading and writing files.

Let's assume I have a very simple function like:

```
int f(int fd_in, int fd_out)
{
    char buf[4096];
    char* bufp = buf;
    ssize_t ret, wr;

    ret = read(fd_in, buf, sizeof(buf));
    /* ... */

    while (ret > 0)
    {
        wr = write(fd_out, bufp, ret);
        /* ... */
    }

    return wr;
}
```

Now, that I'm a bit more aware of alignment issues, I'm starting to think this will actually be suboptimal because the buffer will be aligned for `char`.

Does it seem reasonable to use a different (larger) integral type for buffer in order to obtain a 'stronger' alignment? Will it make reads/writes more optimal? How far do the benefits go? Is using `posix_memalign` to get even more alignment than integral types can achieve a better solution?

Comment: No, why? If you are reading bytes, `char` or `unsigned char` works  well.

Comment: I am reading the whole buffer, and writing the whole buffer (hopefully). I just thought that the underlying implementation could actually optimize the read to larger chunks if the buffer was aligned properly.

Comment: We are likely using virtual memory in the program, while the disk I/O works on physical memory. Just trust the OS to handle this properly!

Comment: Yes, the OS will just read into its own buffers. But then there's the performance of copying the data from them into my buffer and back… well, unless the virtual memory will magically handle that as well.

Comment: 1) don't over-estimate the cost of memcpy(). 2) the 4096 sized buffers span multiple cache slots (64 byte size, IIRC). 3) The OS has its own buffers, too. 4) on a partial read+write you are screwed anyway. 5) **the cost of two system calls (read+write) is much higher than the memcpy's (aligned or unaligned)** 6) (in Linux) there is a in-kernel bufferless function for this (copyfd, or such), implemented as a systemcall. 6) you could always try to measure the difference: `int buff[4096 / sizeof(int)];` would at least be int-aligned.

Comment: @wildplasser: Well, but the cost of using a better-aligned variable type is close to zero, isn't it? And about the first 6) I think you may be referring to `splice()` but it requires one of the fds to be a pipe. There's `sendfile()` but it has very unportable semantics AFAICS. 6/2) I'll probably try but I'm afraid I'm not suited well for measuring and I can get easily confused by something irrelevant ;). In any case, I think either of you may want to put your opinion as an answer.

Comment: If you are worried about speed, I would use fread() and not read() or work with memory mapped files.

Comment: Maybe I should turn it into a bullet list ;-) sendfile is indeed the name. It not only avoids the copying to/from userspace but also a lot of context switches. again: context switches (syscalls) are *extremely* costly. (comparable XX times the the cost of copying a 4K buffer (with XX in the order of 10...100) That is the reason why short reads(network) are to be avoided.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- don't over-estimate the cost of memcpy(). On current machines, memcpy runs "faster than the bus", and spends a lot of its time waiting for cache slots to be pulled in.
- the 4096-sized buffers span multiple cache slots (64 byte size, IIRC).
- The OS has its own buffers, too. (the chunks have to be copied from network buffers, or from DMA memory, for disk)
- on a partial read+write, you are screwed anyway. Your code is prepared to recieve and send 13 bytes. or 133 or 1333. Or 4095. Or 4096. In most cases, the *next* read/write will not be aligned nicely.  The good news: for diskfiles, the size will probably be a multiple of 512, anyway.
- the cost of two system calls (read+write) is much higher than the memcpy's (aligned or unaligned) (there is a nice table of estimated costs inside the cover of the Gray&Reuter book. maybe a bit outdated, but still very instructive)
- (in Linux) there is a in-kernel bufferless function for this (copyfd, or such) **UPDATE** : *sendfile()* is the name, implemented as a systemcall.
- you could always try to measure the difference: int buff[4096 / sizeof(int)]; would at least be int-aligned. Best way would be to use an union of an int array and a char array. Unions are always aligned to the requirements of the pickyest member.

Comment: Hm, why the union? Unless I'm missing something, it should be perfectly valid to cast `int[]` to `char*`, doesn't it?

Comment: Yes, there is nothing wrong with that. But the union would avoid the cast, and might look cleaner.

Comment: Well, I've just started preparing the measure and gcc doesn't allow me to set stack alignment below 16 bytes ;).